# Why does running Redshift commands from crontab does not seem to work?

Tags: linux, display, cron, brightness, redshift

About redshift:

> Redshift adjusts the color temperature of your screen according to your surroundings.

A typical redshift command that I use is `redshift -O 9999` which sets the screen color temperature at 9999K. Following a polyphasic sleep schedule, I prefer to change my screen color a few times a day.

So here's part of my crontab:

```
LOW='redshift -O 1000'
HIGH='redshift -O 9999'

30 4 * * * $LOW
45 12 * * * $LOW
45 20 * * * $LOW
0 6,15,23 * * * $HIGH
```

It doesn't do anything. I checked the syslog, it does run, but when I catch the output in a file, the file is empty.

Why does this not work? Are there any alternatives to Redshift I could try?

Comment: Commands ran from `cron` don't have the shell environment variables such as `DISPLAY` set. Consider what happens when you replace your command in cron with `env`. You need to set the `DISPLAY` variable.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Thanks Dan D. This worked:

```
LOW='redshift -O 1000'
HIGH='redshift -O 9999'
DISPLAY=:0.0

30 4 * * * $LOW
45 12 * * * $LOW
45 20 * * * $LOW
0 6,15,23 * * * $HIGH
```

Comment: how did this work? Didn't the comment from Dan D. say cron doesn't work for redshift?